# Firefox gradient not working

Tags: css, firefox, position, gradient

I created small web page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
       html
       {
        position: fixed; 
       }
       body {
       background: radial-gradient(ellipse at center, rgba(141,141,141,0) 0,rgba(141,141,141,1) 100%);
       }

    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>TEST</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

It's small example to illustrate problem but I have bigger application where is the same. When I add position: fixed to html tag gradient on body tag stops working. It works fine on Google Chrome, Internet Explorer, Microsoft Edge but not on Firefox. I can add that when a change gradient to background-color or backgorund-image it works fine. Firefox version:53.0.3. Do you have any ideas how to deal with that?

Answer (score 0):

Firefox had some [bugs](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=627885) related to `radial gradient`, so try with below syntax

```
background: radial-gradient(ellipse at 50% 50%, #ffffff 0%, #8D8D8D 100%);
```

or `background: radial-gradient(ellipse at center, #ffffff 0%, #8D8D8D 100%);`

or Try with -moz- suffix,

```
background: -moz-radial-gradient(ellipse at center, rgba(141,141,141,0) 0, rgba(141,141,141,1) 100%);
background: radial-gradient(ellipse at center, rgba(141,141,141,0) 0, rgba(141,141,141,1) 100%);
```

Comment: unfortunately this didn't help

Comment: Updated my answer, hope it will help

Comment: It also dosen't work. I think that is not bug related to radial gradient becouse when i remove "position: fixed" gradient is working properly

Comment: Ohh, I have not noticed `position:fixed`, if that's the case then it should not work even in chrome, I don't know how is it impacting Firefox.

Comment: I think there is some bug in Firefox but I hope that there is way to deal with them.